# How do I debug "Getting your selection..." in Android Auto

Tags: android, android-auto

I forked Timber (https://github.com/naman14/Timber), and I am trying to add Android Auto support. I got the app showing up on the virtual head unit, and I can select a song, and it plays. However, instead of showing progress and playback controls, it shows "Getting your selection..."

Now the question is: how do I debug it. As far as I can see from the point when I click on the song, to a few minutes later there are no relevant errors in Logcat. So how can I get some idea of what's going wrong? What does Android Auto is expected to do in that scenario that my app might not be fulfilling?

P.S. this is similar to another question on the same issue, however replacement of `Context` from `this` to `getBaseContext()` does not help, and I am actually curious what is the right way to debug this.